# Is there any event for Footnotes added/removed

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have to add footnotes to my plugin and need a monitor to know when Footnotes added to document, Is there an event like Footnote_Add, Footnote_Edit and Footnote_Delete, such event in contentcontrols ContentControlAfterAdd for Footnotes ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, there are no events for the `Footnotes` object.

Instead try `WindowSelectionChange` of the Word `Application` object. But ensure to use performances as less as possible since that event is raised regularly.

Comment: i used it, and check the range status to make sure it footnote, thank you